# Frequent Loss of Domain Connectivity

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

I have this one new Windows 7 desktop that (and it's clones (different network IDs)) looses domain trust relationship much more often than any other Windows 7 computers in the office.

We use 2003 as AD DC.

I have discovered this when and updated user logon script wasn't executing. Tried run gpupdate /force and received `processing of group policy failed because of lack of connectivity to the domain controller`.

Anyone got ideas where to start troubleshooting? We recently moved from Sophos to Avira, so AV doesn't seem to have influence on it. It's a mint install, so I wonder what I could've screwed up...

Comment: Start with DNS. Are the clients configured with the correct DNS servers? Are the correct DNS zones present and do the correct A and SRV exist? Anything in the DNS or AD event logs on the Domain Controllers?

Comment: Lack of connectivity to the domain controller is not the same as loss of domain trust relationship.

Comment: Also, tell us a little about your network... multiple offices or just 1? Multiple subnets or just 1?

Comment: Agree with @RyanRies, when the issue occurs are you able to log into the PC using a domain account?

Comment: Hi All, I will double check the DNS, but it does connect to the shares without any issues. I know the lack of connectivity isn't the same, but I was presuming it was connected. There is one office with 30 desktops, and 1 main server with slaves (not an AD expert, don't know the exact terminology). No subnets or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, log into the computer using a local account and try to ping the domain name.

If you can't, start there (it could be anything from a bad cable to bad DNS settings to a routing problem).

If you can, the problem becomes more complex, but is generally still a DNS problem of some kind.

As a general rule, the authoritative nameservers for your AD domain should be domain controllers, ultimately.  This means that all your hosts have to be using DNS controlled by you; if someone has managed to statically configure something like 8.8.8.8 in your DNS settings, or you are using public DNS resolvers as "secondary" DNS servers, you will get problems like this.

It's also possible, though unlikely, that some malware or something is trying but failing to man-in-the-middle traffic to the DC; the solution to that is generally to reimage the workstation.  It's probably DNS though, and not this.

Comment: I can confirm DNS settings are correct and do no differ from any other workstation in the building (DHCP).

Comment: How about the ping?  Another thing to look at is that sometimes you have DCs in your domain that no longer exist - check DNS for them.

Comment: No issues with pinging. As far as I know there never was any other DCs in the network.

Comment: Consider using dcdiag, and particularly `dcdiag /test:dns`.

Comment: Okay, you might be right about the DNS, there are some failures, but I am not sure how to interpret them. Here's the [log](http://pastebin.com/1gNhJ44t).

Comment: Bump. Anyone checked the log at the pastebin? http://pastebin.com/1gNhJ44t